# Can I ask about communication protocol performances?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to build a solution that will make me able to test if a solution over Ethernet is faster than the same solution over DDS. However I don't know how to proceed. I have some clues to begin with. But I thought I might get more suitable solutions by asking.

Is this type of question suitable for Stackoverflow ?

Answer (score 2):

No, that would fall under the "primarily opinion-based" close reason:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

It invites discussion and is not really suitable for any site in the StackExchange network. However, you could find a chat room in which to ask it.

Comment: So is there a solution for me to get a hint on where I should go to have an answer ?

Comment: See my update. This sort of question isn't really accepted anywhere on the network, but you can try chat.

Comment: Okay good idea ! Which room shall I ask in ? Shall I create a room ?

Comment: Some good candidates look like the site-specific rooms of [Networkengineering.SE], [SF], or [Electronics.SE].